# Как сделать поиск по MySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Сделал поиск с помощью MATCH AGAINST, работает нормально, но ищет плохо. )) Допустим, ищу слово "работа", если в таблице оно есть, то данные выводятся, но если такого слова нет, а есть слово "работу, то он уже его не покажет. ( Как сделать, чтоб он искал и похожие слова?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно использовать дополнительный морфологический словарь либо стеммер.
Я обычно использую стеммер для простых сайтов. Результаты вполне сносные.

- Пример стеммера: http://forum.dklab.ru/s/php-7/advises-19/14279/
- Пример работы стеммера: http://02.gibdd.ru/search.htm?search=%F8%F2%F0%E0%F4